# Obtener firma con tablet android para formulario PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Buenas tardes amigos.

El día de hoy por necesidades laborales me surgió la necesidad de realizar un pequeño formulario para tomar los datos de unos clientes, esta labor la van a hacer unos compañeros desde unas tablet, decidí hacerlo en php para que los datos me los enviara a una DB en mysql.
Ahora los jefes me preguntan si hay alguna forma de que cliente pueda realizar una firma en la misma tablet, esto para autorizar el envió de información a través de correo electrónico o telefónicamente.

Mi pregunta es: Es posible capturar la firma desde la pantalla de la tablet y enviarla como imagen a la DB?

De antemano muchas gracias

Comment: En tu pais es valida una firma impresa, en argentina la unica forma de autorizar algo es mediante firma digital conociendo la clave publica del firmante para que dicho sea valido legalmente. Ya que si no es un mecanismo valido legalmente deberias replantearselo a tu jefe que cambie el mecanismo a poner su clave por ejemplo. Segundo las firma se vera bien, probaste intentando firmar en un paint en una tablet creo que sale cualquier cosa menos una firma. saludos

Comment: Haz podido encontrar algo? Yo solo he encontrado para firmar y guardar la imagen pero usando navegadores de PC, pero en dispositivos móviles no funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes ocupar alguna librería que utilice canvas para dibujar y exportar el dibujo.

Lo que te sugiero es gurdar la imágen en tu servidor y en la bd guardar el path de la imágen para posteriormente acceder a ella.

Aquí te dejo una librería que se ve fácil de usar.

[link de la librería](http://intridea.github.io/sketch.js/)

Comment: Hola Amigo, he tratado de incluir la libreria pero no me funciona.
Incluí el archivo sketch.js en el proyecto y llame el scrip que necesitaba y que me dejaba guardar pero no me funciona.
 me podrias dar algunas indicaciones ?
Gracias

Comment: Que es lo que no te funciona?